# pivot to total per week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that i am trying to write to return the amount of times and instance occurs in a database and group by week and product as defined by the database. below is my query:

```
SELECT WeekCompleted, Product, COUNT(OrderNumber) as CorrectionCount FROM(
SELECT 
p.Abbreviation as Product
,CAST(oi.OrderID as VARCHAR(MAX))+'.'+CAST(oi.OrderItemID as VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderNumber
,CASE
    WHEN o.ClientID IN (56156, 56394) 
        THEN DATEADD(week, datepart(ww, dbo.GetLatestMilestoneDate(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID, 80)) 
            - 1, DATEADD(DAY, @@datefirst - DATEPART(weekday, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
            + '-01-01') - 6, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01'))
    ELSE DATEADD(week, datepart(ww, dbo.GetLatestMilestoneDate(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID, 130)) 
    - 1, DATEADD(DAY, @@datefirst - DATEPART(weekday, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
    + '-01-01') - 6, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01')) 
    END AS WeekCompleted
,CASE   
    WHEN o.ClientID IN (56156,56394) THEN dbo.GetLatestMilestoneDate(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID, 80)
    ELSE dbo.GetLatestMilestoneDate(oi.OrderID, oi.OrderItemID, 130) END AS LastCompleted
FROM
OrderItems oi
LEFT JOIN OrderItemMilestones oim on oim.OrderID = oi.OrderID and oim.OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
JOIN Orders o on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
WHERE
oim.MilestoneID = 90
and QueueID = 0
) src
WHERE LastCompleted >= '2012-10-01'
GROUP BY WeekCompleted, Product
```

here is more info needed

```
 dbo.getlatestmilestonedate() returns a datetime date in this format: mm:dd:yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

and a sample table of data i currently have:

```
WeekCompleted           Product    CorrectionCount
2012-09-30 00:00:00.000 Product1    5
2012-10-07 00:00:00.000 Product1    7
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Product1    7
2012-09-30 00:00:00.000 Product2    18
2012-10-07 00:00:00.000 Product2    28
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000 Product2    16
```

This data is returning exactly how i want it to so no change is needed to the original data unless needed to accomplish final goal, which is this:

```
WeekCompleted               Product1        Product2
2012-09-30 00:00:00.000      5                18
2012-10-07 00:00:00.000      7                28 
2012-10-14 00:00:00.000      7                16
```

I think i need to pivot this, but every time i try i only run into syntax errors and dont quite yet understand the pivot syntax.

Comment: if anyone needs more info on anything i can fill in the gaps

Comment: will you have more than two products that you want as columns?

Comment: yes, figured two was enough to get the syntax correct though

Comment: well my question is more asking do you want to return an unknown number of products as columns?

Comment: yes, i added a select * from(rest of my query) then put the pivot after so i only have to define the products in the pivot. is there a way to not have to define each product there as well?

Comment: sounds like you will need to use dynamic sql to generate this pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select weekcompleted, product1, product2
from (your query) src
pivot (sum(CorrectionCount) for Product in ([Product1],[Product2])) p
```

If your products can vary then you have to build up the pivot query above using dynamic SQL

```
declare @columns varchar(4000)
select @columns = '';
select @columns = ',[' + productname +']' 
    from (select distinct productname from products) v
select @columns = substring (@columns, 2, len(@columns))

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
select @sql = 'select weekcompleted, ' + @columns 
+ ' from (your query) src '
+ ' pivot (sum(CorrectionCount) for Product in ('+@columns+')) p'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: i get a syntax error when i put the query into (your query) im putting everything from select p.abbreviation as product to ) src. here is the error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '+CAST(oi.OrderItemID as VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderNumber
 ,CASE
  WHEN o.ClientID IN (56156, 56394) 
   THEN DATEADD(week, datepa'.

Comment: @wondergoat77 You'll need to double up any quotes in your query - ie: replace `'` with `''` (two single quotes, not a double quote). Or you could put your query into a view, which might be easier if its static.

Comment: did that and im still getting the same error, i assume i need to also add the product and count(ordernumber) as correction count to the first line in 'select @ sql =' is that correct?

Comment: @wondergoat77 No. Just replace `your query` with your whole query.

Comment: i put the entire thing up top in an edit if you dont mind taking a look

Comment: i had to replace product name with abbreviation(which is what that would be in the database) and now get an error pointing at this: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.

Comment: You're probably missing a close bracket

Comment: yep thats what it was, ive got the query working now but im only getting 1 product as a result. The weeks are showing correctly though